# Windows Update failed, system now failing to boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod

I have a windows 10 system where updates were continuing to fail. On one particular attempt the machine blue screened after a reboot to continue the installation attempt. The installation would routinely stop at 'We were unable to update, undoing installation' (words to that effect)

Boot fails with bluescreen: `CRITICAL_SERVICE_FAILED`.

`DISM` (in various forms, I might be missing an important one) and `sfc` (`\scannow` and some 'offboot' options) all appear to run on the OS drive and find nothing of interest.

When the startup troubleshooter loads, Startup Options>Restart doesn't give a list of options but instead error `d00000452`, so I can't try safe mode. 'Startup Repair' fails after 'Diagnosing your PC' with 'Start-up repair couldn't repair your PC'.

The 'Uninstall update' options either fail or can't find an update to revert.

`chkdsk` did find some errors and fix them, being able to find no more.

What's left for the machine, what other tools are available to resolve it?

Windows 10 Professional, native update from Windows 7 Professional some years ago.

Comment: Sounds like a storage device failure

Comment: Try to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). If it fails, check the health of the disk.

Comment: @harrymc is the repair install possible from a non-booting system? It looks like no.

Comment: If the computer cannot boot, how did you do DISM and SFC?

Comment: from command line recovery

Comment: @JCollins - It is not to repair Windows outside of Windows in its current state.  An in-place repair of Windows absolutely will require the ability to boot into Windows and mount a Windows ISO and launching the Setup.exe. Any other method of installing Windows will result in a clean install.

Comment: That seems iunnecessary since the installer will restart the machine anyway. Nonetheless. How can a system be broken if neither DISM and sfc can find any issues?

Comment: Repair install in this case is impossible. I suggest to reinstall Windows from USB. You risk losing your installed apps and settings, if the installation doesn't find your current Windows, so ensure you have backups. Don't format the disk during the installation.